# Using formula change the cell orientation, if another cell matches a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rotation, orientation

Is there a formula to change cell orientation? All the tutorials/ web pages I searched for, only show how to change orientation using the orientation tab. I am trying to avoid using VBA code. So, can anyone please suggest if there is a way to change the cell orientation by 180 degrees using formula/ functions.

Comment: Please mock up some data and expected output and [edit] your question to include the visual representation.  It will help use understand better what you want.

Comment: you cannot change the orientation with a formula, nor can you use conditional formatting.  vba is the only way with your current setup.

Comment: Could you insert a new column D in your vehicle Table? Column C pointed left and column D pointed right.  Then depending on option picked in you main table it either references column C or D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you wanted to avoid VBA, but there's no other way. If you want to actively modify the formatting of the cell, macros (subs) are the only way. Excel formulas cannot modify formatting as a rule, only the cell content.

If you wanted to try VBA, this is the code you should use:

Right-click on your worksheet tab (Standard Driving Scenarios) and paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Excel.Range)
    Dim switchColumn  As Integer
    Dim vehicleColumnFirst As Integer
    Dim vehicleColumnLast As Integer

    switchColumn = 12
    vehicleColumnFirst = 36
    vehicleColumnLast = 39

    If target.Column = 12 Then
        If target.Value = "Yes" Then
            Range(Cells(target.Row, vehicleColumnFirst), Cells(target.Row, vehicleColumnLast)).Orientation = 90
        ElseIf target.Value = "No" Then
            Range(Cells(target.Row, vehicleColumnFirst), Cells(target.Row, vehicleColumnLast)).Orientation = -90
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Don't esitate to ask if you have any questions.